# rails: form on submit should go to a custom url containing values of two dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

i have a little problem with making a custom url from two value got from  dropdown menus.
i am trying to use jquery to that. these two values have their ids as

```
#convertor_from_currency
#convertor_to_currency
```

### jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#currency_form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var from = $('#convertor_from_currency').val();
            var to = $('#convertor_to_currency').val();
            var url_end = from + "-" + to;
            var url = $('#currency_form').attr('action') + '/' + url_end;
            $('#currency_form').attr('action', url);
            $('#currency_form').submit();
            //alert(url);
        });
 </script>
```

### and this is a markup of the form:

```
<%= form_for :convertor , :html => {:id => "currency_form"}, :url => {:controller => "converter", :action => "show" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :from_currency %>
    <%= f.select :from_currency, options_for_select(currencies,  @from_cur)  %>

    <%= f.label :to_currency %>
    <%= f.select :to_currency, options_for_select(currencies,  @to_cur), :required => true %>
    <%= f.submit "Calculate", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", id: "submitButton" %> 
<% end %>
```

### routes

```
root 'converter#index'
# get "converter/show"
match '/currencies/', to: 'converter#show',   via: [:post]
```

on submitting i want the url to be:

```
'/currencies/url_end
```

where "url_end" is a concatenation of the values submitted in the form:

```
 #convertor_from_currency
    #convertor_to_currency
```

### updated, this is my controller.

```
class ConverterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
     @amount = params[:convertor][:amount]
     @from_cur = params[:convertor][:from_currency]
     @to_cur = params[:convertor][:to_currency]

     @result = ConverterHelper.show(@from_cur, @to_cur, @amount)
  end
end
```

how do i do this? 
any ideas will be appreciated even if it is using another way other than jquery/javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can help (it worked for me)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#currency_form").submit(function(){
        var from = $('#convertor_from_currency').val();
        var to = $('#convertor_to_currency').val();
        var url_end = from + "-" + to;
        var url = $('#currency_form').attr('action') + '/' + url_end;
        $('form#currency_form').attr('action', url);
        // window.location.href = url
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(url);
        return false;
    });
  });
 </script>
```

you can (un)comment to make it work according to your question

don't forget your routes

```
  root 'converter#index'
  match '/currencies/', to: 'converter#show',   via: [:post]
  post '/currencies/:url' => 'converter#show'
```

**then upvote!!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Can you try rewriting this route:

```
match '/currencies/', to: 'converter#show',   via: [:post]
```

to:

```
match '/currencies/:from-:to', to: 'converter#show',   via: [:post]
```

In this case requests to (for example) /currencies/usd-eur will be routed to converter#show and you will be able to access the currencies in the controller action using params[from] and params[:to].

**UPDATE:**

1. There was an error in javascript code:

This code should work as you expected:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#currency_form").submit(function(e){
        var from = $('#convertor_from_currency').val();
        var to = $('#convertor_to_currency').val();
        var url_end = from + "-" + to;
        var url = $('#currency_form').attr('action') + '/' + url_end;

        $.post(url, $('#currency_form').serialize(), function(data){alert('success');});
        alert(url);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
  });
 </script>
```

You should not call submit on form as long as you are inside submit handler. Instead, you should use $.post(...) to submit the form data. Form data can be serialized as in my example to be sent with the $.post(). You should have added "});" before closing  tag.

1. One of routing configurations that should work for you:

   match '/currencies/' => 'converter#index', as: :converter
   match '/currencies/:from-:to' => 'converter#show',   via: [:post]

   your form should use converter_path helper as the action url. And the JS code should submit the form to /currencies/:from-:to.
2. You need to update the form in the view to:

   {:id => "currency_form"}, :url => converter_path do |f| %>
3. You can use this sample code in your controller to ensure that the form is submitted correctly:

   def show
     @amount = params[:convertor][:amount]
     @from_cur = params[:convertor][:from_currency]
     @to_cur = params[:convertor][:to_currency]

   #@result = ConverterHelper.show(@from_cur, @to_cur, @amount)
     render text: "text"
   end

You can uncomment the line and remove render once you see that the form is correctly processed on the server.

Comment: is their a way i can use the instance variables?. because i am getting this error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"converter"}

Comment: i have tried it but still the routes seems to have a problem. please try check my updates on the question, don't you think there is a simpler way?

Comment: Can you post the error that you get using my code? As an alternative, I can suggest using [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) and specify :remote => "true" for the form. You will not need to use any JS for this task.